# Benefits of tree tents over typical shelters?

Tags: tents, shelter

I've recently learned about tree tents such as [Tentsile](http://www.tentsile.com/) and while they certainly look interesting and fun, they seem to combine the drawbacks of hammocks (heat loss due to wind and need for trees) with the drawbacks of a tent (size, weight and complexity).

So, in which situations would this type of tent have more benefits than existing shelters?

Comment: It looks like a cute concept, and it might be fun to do. But what do you do on a multi-day trip when some of your campsites don't work for this technique (e.g., you're above tree line)? What if the trees aren't big enough to handle this amount of tension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a 'pod' hammock tent for backpacking and enjoy it a lot.
This bigger tree tent wouldn't be for backpacking but for car camping with friends or family.
Sleeping in a suspended tent is clean, dry and more comfortable then sleeping on the ground.
(everything being subject to your own opinion)

Answer (score 2):

Likely to be less buggy than a hammock, and doesn't have the weight of hiking poles.
Also (and I'm not sure I'd try this), if you are concerned about being trampled/attacked by large animals, you could install it several feet up the tree.

Finally, the floor looks flatter than a hammock, and the 3-point tiedown seems to keep it from rotating.

Answer (score 1):

Look fun, but seems entirely a gimmick if you ask me. If you wanted to save weight you'd bivvy, if you wanted to be comfortable a tent is much more flexible. With my fully practical head on, I can't see any useful benefits. They look comfortable though I'd imagine you and everything in the tent would slide towards the middle of the tent.

> in which situations would this type of tent have more benefits than
>   existing shelters?

Because fun and different....and you could bounce.

Answer (score 1):

Benefits are probably quite limited. It allows you to camp where ground conditions do not suit - e.g. very wet, rough or not level ground, in dense or fragile (that you care about) undergrowth. Leaves a smaller trace of an overnight stop - lower impact of camp - good for military use or those who care about such things. Protection of sometimes poisonous things that bite in the night are all things that come to mind - while maintaining the group structure (unlike hammocks which are solo). Its current weight would prevent it being used for most of these situations.

Looks like fun and interesting and the benefits are probably not the reason you would buy or use one. I have not tried the product and don't particularly subscribe to the philosophy eluded to by the manufacturer, but should the opportunity present itself I am certainly a starter for a difference experience. I suspect it will be around for a while, but will always be a niche product.